# Javascript 404 error detection

Tags: javascript, http-status-code-404

I have a page with a custom URL protocol link on it. The custom URL protocol is registered on the user's system when they install an exe. When a user clicks a custom url protocol link on a web page, it launches that exe (all currently working great). But when they click that link and don't have the exe installed locally yet, they get a standard error page in the browser.
So if they don't have the local exe I want the browser to present a custom error page instead that tells them they need to download the exe. I think it might be as simple as javascript listening for that error when the link is clicked and if the error is there, present the custom error page. But I don't know how to do that. There error page is a "The webpage cannot be displayed. Most likely cause: Some content or files on this webpage require a program that you do not have installed." (404 error I think?)
Any help is super appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest making a test function that determines whether the protocol has been installed:

1. Make an AJAX call from your page to a test page using your protocol.
2. If this succeeds with no errors then the remaining parts of the page can use this protocol safely.
3. If the AJAX call fails then you will know that the protocol has not been installed.

Jquery would make light work of this approach. You could even dynamically change the URLs of your links depending on the success/failure of your test function. The links could be made to make a pop-up warning that the user needs to install the protocol handler.

Comment: Appreciate the response. I guess I wasn't looking as much for a generalized solution as I was specific code. I know it can also be done via javascript, but not sure I have much preference. What I do know is that I can't do it in any language! ;-) I was hoping for code examples.....

Comment: By the way, you said to make a call to a "test page". the protocol is calling a local exe. So you are saying to make an ajax call to the local system registry to see if the url protocol is in there? isn't it easier to just call the actual url protocol with a function and if it errors present an error or it it doesn't continue the call and launch the local exe? I might be misunderstanding but it sounds like you're adding an unnecessary step to the process. This is occurring on a link click, not on a page load.

Comment: No, I'm saying make a call to a test page using your installed protocol. If it is there then it will succeed. The answer is as general as your question... Make your question more specific and I'll happily provide a code-based solution.

Comment: Thanks Lee. I'm saying I can't write any of that ajax code. So the solution you described sounds great but without the exact code to do what you're indicating I don't fully understand or can't proceed. I thought my original question was pretty specific, but perhaps it is my lack of knowledge in the area causing the problem. Not sure how to be any more specific.

Comment: @Tim - It would help if you described the type of data you're serving via your new protocol and what your URLs look like, etc.

Comment: All I am doing is launching a local exe. That's it. Not serving any data or sending any commands to it, etc. The link is simply ctp://myapp.exe. It is a local player app for an online subscription website. I want users to be able to click a "play now" button on the site and it launches the local player already installed. When the player is installed with InnoSetup it is creating a new registry entry that sets up the custom URL protocol. That is all functioning well and the link is launching the app just fine - assuming the exe is on the computer already. (continued...)

Comment: I am just looking for a way to alert anyoe who clicks that Play Now button but hasn't installed the local player yet that they need to do that. So the pages needs to launch the exe if it's present or show an error telling the user to download it if it is not. I figured the easiest way to do that was to simply watch or a 404 error when clicking that link. if the error shows it is because the user doesn't have the player installed.

Answer (score 0):

404 is an HTTP status code, so I don't think you can expect that when you invoke your custom protocol.  You might try hooking into `window.onerror` but I'd be kind of surprised if that worked.

What I've done in a similar situation is to include a browser plugin in the installation.  Then you can check from script if the handler is installed before the user tries to invoke it.  Also, you can have your plugin report the installed version so you can prompt users to upgrade.  The downside is that you need to handle multiple plugin models and architectures if you don't want to restrict your supported browsers.